# How store binary tree nodes in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, binary-tree

I want to create a binary tree in react.I am using **react-d3-tree** component for displaying the tree.
For **react-d3-tree** the data should be of the format

```
const myTreeData = [
  {
    name: 'Top Level',
    attributes: {
      keyA: 'val A',
      keyB: 'val B',
      keyC: 'val C',
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Level 2: A',
        attributes: {
          keyA: 'val A',
          keyB: 'val B',
          keyC: 'val C',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Level 2: B',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

How to store data on firestore so that I can retrieve it and get it as the above array format?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pass your `myTreeData` variable encapsulated in an object, as follows:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();

const myTreeData = [
  {
    name: 'Top Level',
    attributes: {
      keyA: 'val A',
      keyB: 'val B',
      keyC: 'val C',
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Level 2: A',
        attributes: {
          keyA: 'val A',
          keyB: 'val B',
          keyC: 'val C',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Level 2: B',
      },
    ],
  },
];

db.collection('yourCollection').add({tree: myTreeData})
.then(function(newDocRef) {
    return newDocRef.get();
}).then(function(doc) {
    console.log("JavaScript Object:", doc.data().tree);
    console.log("JSON:", JSON.stringify(doc.data().tree));
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

---

The above code saves the `{tree: myTreeData}` object in a Firestore document and gets back this document in order to log the value of the `tree` field in the console (as a JavaScript Object and as a JSON)

Comment: I want to add each node seperately.then retrieve all nodes to the above array format.What I want is the data modal in firestore to store each nodes

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you mean by "each node seperately"? Which nodes? Only `name`, `attribute`, `children` or also `keyA`, `keyB`, etc... Please update your question with as much detail as possible on your exact goal and in particular how the different writes will be organized in time?

Comment: Its a binary tree consisting of nodes.Each node consists of  name and attributes fields.Children are the left and right node of each nodes in the binary tree

Comment: Without much details it is difficult to help you more. If you want to update the field with new array elements and/or new nodes, you should use a mix of calls to [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#update_elements_in_an_array) and [nested objects update by using the "dot notation"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#update_fields_in_nested_objects) depending on the exact update.

Comment: Note that you may need to read the value of the `tree` field to update its value in your front-end before saving the new value (for example if you want to update an object included in a array element). Again, without more details it is difficult to give more guidance.

Comment: What I want is the data modal of firestore.How each nodes to be stored as documents and how to link that documents.And retrieve the nodes in documents to the above object of array format.

Comment: Ok, have you tried a first implementation? Do you encounter specific problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206045/discussion-between-arjun-sr-and-renaud-tarnec).